# Роли пользователя

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular-routing, angular

Как правильно реализовать структура проекта, если у пользователей могут быть разные роли. Например если пользователь админ, то у него отображаеться 4 кнопки(удалить, изменить, добавить, посмотреть). Если менеджер то 2 кнопки(изменить, посмотреть). А если обычный юзер то доступна только одна кнопка - посмотреть. Сейчас создал директиву, которая делает запрос на сервер, получает роль даного юзера и в зависимости от роли решает показывать кнопку или нет. Правильно ли, что дериктива, каждый раз делает запрос на сервер? Может сделать чтобы при авторизации роль пользователя сохранялась в localStorage? Или вообще как-то по-другому все это передалать. Жду ваших советов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно один раз запросить их при загрузке приложения и положить их в сервис, который будет отвечать за предоставленные разрешения.

Например такой:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleService {
  private _role: string;

  constructor(){
     this._role = 'admin'; //получить от сервера
  }

  set role(r: string){
     this._role = r;
  }

  get role(): string{
     return this._role;
  }

  isUserAdmin(): boolean{
   return role === 'admin';
  }
}
```

а в компоненте заинжектить:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tmp',
  template: '<button *ngIf="roleService.isUserAdmin()">AdminButton</button>'
})
export class TmpComponent { 
   constructor(roleService: RoleService){
   }
}
```

Сервис конечно же необходимо указать в файле модуля в поле `providers`.